# Iphone out of space due to duplicate podcasts?

Tags: itunes, iphone, podcasts

My iphone 4s (iOS 7.1.2) is out of storage space.

After spending time pruning old podcasts from my iTunes manager, I began to 'browse' my iphone.

I can see on my iPhone many identical podcasts.  These are in read-only mode, I cannot do anything except to play them. For example:
[image: Example iphone browse from itunes with duplicate podcasts]

There is only one iTunes entry in the Career Tools podcast for Resume Update 2014, and there are 17 on my iPhone.

Does anyone know how to remove these extra podcasts for all that I subscribe to?

Comment: Update:  deleting the offending podcast doesnt fix this.

Comment: Restoring iphone to factory settings from the phone's settings interface, and then restoring from backup has resolved the issue.  We'll see how permanent it it.